# Even if there is data, why is the form verification message output saying that there is no data at the first submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

When you click the + button, a new form is created and the current time is entered as the default value of the time input

If you submit directly from the new form, the form validation will output a form validation error asking you to enter the time in the input that the current time is being output as the default value.

Once again, the data will be transmitted normally.

When a button is clicked, the called function receives the index value, which is the location of the button clicked as a parameter

This is an update function with a new array by putting a new data object next to the parameter index in the existing list state value.

In my opinion

Click + button (list: [{...}, {...}, {...}])

form Add function call (add new data and run setList) re-landering progress

list: [{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}] 4

Since it is updated with the latest data in this order, the current value will be output on the screen

When you first submit it, you output an error because it says there is no value, but if you submit it again, it goes over normally.

Is there anything I'm missing or misunderstanding?

Please teach us.

The library is using react-hook-form.

```
main.jsx

 const [list, setList] = useState(data.result);//Get data via loader

const handlerAddTr = (e, index, schedule) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newItem = {
      NO: schedule.NO,
      DAY: "",
      YOIL: "",
      HOLYDAY_YN: "",
      HOLYDAY: "",
      TIME: timeString,//currentTime
      TYPE: 1,
      GOV_NAME: "",
      GOV_DEPT: "",
      RQU_CONTENT: "",
      RQU_NAME: "", 
      RQU_TEL: "",
      SERVER: "",
      WEB: "",
      VISIT_ETC: "",
      RESULT: 1,
      WORK_NAME: "",
      HOLY_NAME: "",
      METTING: "",
      ETC: "",
      COPY: true,
    };

    const newItems = [...list];
    newItems.splice(index + 1, 0, newItem);
    setList(newItems);
  };

return (
    <div>
        {list.length !== 0 ? (
          list.map((day, index) => (
            <SchedulerList
              Key={day.NO}
              day={day}
              index={index}
              handlerAddTr={handlerAddTr}
              handlerMinusTr={handlerMinusTr}
              handlerTime={handlerTime}
              updateTime={updateTime}
              onSubmit={onSubmit}
            />
          ))
        ) : (
          <tr>
            <td colspan="16">no data.</td>
          </tr>
        )}
      </div>
);
```

```
list.jsx
const List = ({
  Key,
  day,
  index,
  handlerAddTr,
}) => {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    register,
  } = useForm();

  const callSubmit = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      handleSubmit(onSubmit)();
    }
  };

  return (
    <form className="flex" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="NO" value={day.NO} />
        <span className="input">
          {day.DAY} {day.YOIL}{" "}
          {!day.COPY ? (
            <button type="button" onClick={(e) => handlerAddTr(e, index, day)}>
              +
            </button>
          ) : (
            <button type="button" onClick={() => handlerMinusTr(index, day)}>
              -
            </button>
          )}
          <br></br>
          {!day.HOLYDAY ? "" : `(${day.HOLYDAY})`}
        </span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="TIME"
          {...register("TIME", {
            required: "Please enter the time",
            pattern: {
              value: /^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/g,
              message: "Please enter it in time format HH:mm",
            },
          })}
          defaultValue={day.TIME}
          className="input"
          onClick={() => handlerTime(index)}
        />
        <p>{errors.TIME?.message}</p>
      </div>
```

I did a functional update

It didn't work out as I thought

Comment: let me try to understand here.
On first button click do we need to show error or any data?

Comment: thank you
There is no need to display errors or data.
Click the + button to add new data and
A new form will also be added according to the addition.

Comment: okay understood so now even if there is a new data the  the list is old correct?

Comment: New data is added and output to the screen.
The problem is that the data output on the screen and the data sent to the submit do not match.
display data : {NO:...} !== submit data: {NO:...}

'NO' data hand over the default key value of the + button data to the function's parameters
It is used as a key value for new data.